# NextJS PWA compatibility with older browsers

Tags: webpack, next.js, babeljs, progressive-web-apps

We need our project to be supported on old browsers. All the code is compatible with Chrome 30+ except Next PWA script in the main.js output file.

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator && typeof caches !== 'undefined') {
if (true) {
caches.has('start-url').then(function(has) {
if (!has) {
caches.open('start-url').then(c => c.put('/', new Response('', {status: 200})))
}
})
}
```

As you can see, the arrow functions were not converted by the babel. Although I have used arrow functions in the entire project, there are no arrow functions in other places in the output js file.
It seems the Next PWA is just skipping babel.

The project is written in typescript

```
next-pwa@5.4.4
next@11.1.2
```

Comment: What is `compilerOptions:target` in your `tsconfig.json`? I think you can change this one to support older browsers.

Comment: @Pieterjan No it doesn't matter. I've already set it to es5.